# React Native conditional render temporarily displays content

Tags: react-native

I have a conditional in my render function. When the if statement is not met, it temporarily displays prior to the else block displaying.

```
render() {
    let renderedContent = null

    if (this.props.tabLabel === 'Schedule' && this.getReportsForTab(this.props.reports).length === 0) {
      renderedContent = (
        <View style={styles.addInspectionContainer}>
          <Button block primary style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.props.onAddReport()}>Add Inspection</Button>
        </View>
      )
    } else {
      renderedContent =  (
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderReport}
          renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
        />
      )
    }

    return renderedContent
  }
```

This shouldn't be happening. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @zvona It shouldn't be displaying the if blocks code when the else block is what is executed. How do I get it to not show the if blocks code?

Comment: For example, when this.props.tabLabel === 'completed' only the else block should be displayed. Now, the if block is displayed for a few seconds prior to the else block displaying

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem. The if block was displaying when the page wasn't completely loaded. I added a this.props.loaded to the if statement:

```
if (this.props.loaded && this.props.tabLabel === 'Schedule' && this.getReportsForTab(this.props.reports).length === 0)
```